# add generic arguments to implicit operator

Tags: c#

Here is a snippet of my code which is part of bigger codebase for decoupling state from logic:

```
public delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T r1);
public delegate RES FuncRef<T, RES>(ref T r1);

abstract public class State<T> {
    T Value; // internal state 

    public virtual void Use(ActionRef<T> f) {
      // code that modifies the state
    }

    public virtual TRES Use<TRES>(FuncRef<T, TRES> f) {
      // code that modifies the state and returns a value
    }

    // redundant, here just for clarification
    Action<ActionRef<T>> Updater() {
      return f => Use(f); // ok
    }

    public static implicit operator Action<ActionRef<T>>(State<T> instance) {
      return f => instance.Use(f); // implicit updater, ok
    }

    // redundant, here just for clarification
    Func<FuncRef<T, TRES>, TRES> Updater<TRES>() {
      return f => Use(f); // ok
    }

    public static implicit operator Func<FuncRef<T, TRES>, TRES><TRES>(State<T> instance) {
      return f => instance.Use(f); // implicit updater, error
    }
}
```

The first implicit operator compile fine, however the second one fails with syntax error around the `<TRES>` argument
(note that the matching `Updater` member compiles fine)

Is there a way to add the second generic argument here ?

Comment: `<FuncRef<T, TRES><TRES>` ?

Comment: @TheGeneral sorry I got confused with this super confusing stuff, edited my question

Comment: implicit operator <-- can't define generic type

Comment: Can you explain why you need implicit operator ?

Comment: @TimChang you can define a generic type, see the first implicit function

Comment: @TimChang I want to consumers of `State<>` to be able to use it directly without calling `Use(`

Comment: <T><-- this is include in State<T> so it's ok ,but  you can't define other Generic type without "Stage"

Comment: @TimChang do you have a reference to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *introducing* a generic parameter is not possible on implicit operator. Reducing your problem, see even below example will fail to compile.

```
abstract public class State
{
    public static implicit operator Action<T>(State instance) => f => {};
    public static implicit operator Action<T><T><(State instance) => f => { }; // you are trying to do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this way，chang State to State<T,TRES>

```
public delegate void ActionRef<T>(ref T r1);

public delegate RES FuncRef<T, RES>(ref T r1);

public abstract class State<T, TRES>
{
    private T Value;

    public virtual void Use(ActionRef<T> f)
    {
        // code that modifies the state
    }

    public virtual TRES Use<TRES>(FuncRef<T, TRES> f)
    {
        // code that modifies the state and returns a value
        return default;
    }

    private Action<ActionRef<T>> Updater() => Use; // ok

    public static implicit operator Action<ActionRef<T>>(State<T, TRES> instance) => instance.Use; // ok

    private Func<FuncRef<T, TRES>, TRES> Updater<TRES>() => Use; // ok

    public static implicit operator Func<FuncRef<T, TRES>, TRES>(State<T, TRES> instance) => instance.Use;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how I would instantiate this class where I don't know what `TRES` is - it is only deduced by the compiler from the return value of `f`